# So what is the reason behind the claim that you need at least as much swap area as main memory for hibernate to work?

Tags: hibernate, swap

I saw a lot of recommendations claiming that for hibernation the swap partition/file must be at least as large as the main memory. This makes no sense to me. Lets assume I have 8 GB of main memory and 8 GB swap area and want to hibernate:

- case 1: I'm using 4 GB of virtual memory -> 8 GB of swap is unnecessarily large.
- case 2: I'm using 8 GB of virtual memory -> 8 GB of swap is just right.
- case 3: I'm using 12 GB of virtual memory -> 8 GB of swap is too small.

The outcome is: A swap area of size equal to the memory size is sufficient for hibernate IFF it doesn't get used for swapping at all. **So what is the reason behind the claim that you need at least as much swap area as main memory for hibernate to work?**

I know that virtual memory gets used for caching too, and that the cache may be simply discarded, but **what happens to hibernation if a program allocates 12 GB of virtual memory** (given the above memory and swap sizes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple really,

When hibernating the system saves whatever is in RAM to the disk, and if there is not enough room in `swap`, the system will complain and not allow you to hibernate. To avoid this happening, it is best to have at least the same amount of `swap` space as your RAM. In most cases, you don't need any more than this, as the majority of applications almost never use enough RAM for `swap` to be under heavy usage.

However, if you have a small amount of RAM, or if you use a rather heavy application, you will probably want to double the size of your `swap` to accommodate the memory that needs to be written for hibernation.

Comment: That's OK, but with no amount of swap there's a guarantee that hibernate will succeed (it can be all taken as virtual memory), right?

Comment: @maaartinus I'm not sure I understand what you're asking me in this comment? You should be able to hibernate if you follow the recommended setup, because applications won't be allowed to go over a certain level of memory (for stability reasons).

Comment: OK, I'll try it out.